# Post values from multiple range inputs on change in Angular 6 with debounceTime

Tags: rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

In my Angular 6 project i had a component with 3 range inputs and 1 checkbox.
With the checkbox I can link the value of 2 of the 3 range inputs so that if one is changed the other one change accordingly.
When the checkbox is unchecked the second one isn't updated.
When one of range inputs are changed, the values of all 3 controls have to be send to an API.

So far I was successfull.
The problem is that when I change the range input there is a burst of post requests to the API.
I want to reduce the burst of requests.

In the template I have the following controls:

```
<input class="my-custom-range" type="range" [min]="-1 * navControl.engine1.power.max" [max]="navControl.engine1.power.max" [(ngModel)]="controls.throttle1" (ngModelChange)="onChangeThrothel1($event)" [disabled]="!navControl.engine1.isOnline" >
<input class="my-custom-range" type="range" [min]="-1 * navControl.engine2.power.max" [max]="navControl.engine2.power.max" [(ngModel)]="controls.throttle2" (ngModelChange)="onChangeThrothel2($event)" [disabled]="!navControl.engine2.isOnline" >
<mat-slider min="-80" max="80" step="8" thumbLabel="true" vertical="true" [(ngModel)]="controls.mainHelm" (ngModelChange)="changeMainHelm($event)" [disabled]="!navControl.engine1.isOnline" style="margin-top: 4em; height: 100%"></mat-slider>
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="syncEngines">Motor Sync</mat-checkbox>
```

I have some interfaces like this:

```
export interface INavigationRequest {
  engine1: IEngineRequest;
  engine2: IEngineRequest;
}
export interface IEngineRequest {
  id: number;
  requestedPower: number;
  isForwardPropultion: boolean;
  requestedAngle: number;
  correctionPower: number;
  correctionAngle: number;
}
```

In the server.service.ts I have the following:

```
updateEngines(params: INavigationRequest): Observable<INavigationResponse> {
  console.log('update engines', params);
  return this.http.post<INavigationResponse>(`${this.baseUrl}/api/navigation/post/`, params);
}
```

In the component.ts I have the following:

```
public onChangeThrothel1(value): void {
  if (value && this.syncEngines) {
    this.controls.throttle2 = value;
  }
  console.log('1', this.controls.throttle1);
  console.log('2', this.controls.throttle2);
  this.updateNavControl();
}

public onChangeThrothel2(value): void {
  if (value && this.syncEngines) {
    this.controls.throttle1 = value;
  }
  console.log('1', this.controls.throttle1);
  console.log('2', this.controls.throttle2);
  this.updateNavControl();
}

public changeMainHelm(value): void {
  if (value) {
    this.controls.helm = value;
    this.updateNavControl();
  }
}

public updateNavControl(): void {
  let params: INavigationRequest = {
    engine1: {
      id: this.navControl.engine1.id,
      isForwardPropultion: this.navControl.engine1.isForwardPropultion,
      requestedPower: this.controls.throttle1,
      requestedAngle: this.controls.helm,
      correctionPower: this.navControl.engine1.power.correction,
      correctionAngle: this.navControl.engine1.angle.correction
    },
    engine2: {
      id: this.navControl.engine2.id,
      isForwardPropultion: this.navControl.engine2.isForwardPropultion,
      requestedPower: this.controls.throttle2,
      requestedAngle: this.controls.helm,
      correctionPower: this.navControl.engine2.power.correction,
      correctionAngle: this.navControl.engine2.angle.correction
    }
  };
  console.log(params);
  this.server.updateEngines(params).pipe(debounceTime(500), distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(result => {
    console.log('HttpClient [POST] /api/navigation/post', result);
    this.procesEngines(result);
  }, error => {
    console.log(`There was an issue. ${error._body}.`);
  });
}
```

The debounceTime isn't working and every change is submitted.

I think the placement of the debounce time is not in the right place.
Maybe my approach is completely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put all you changes on a single observable and then you can do debouncing and etc.

You can do something like this:

```
private updateQueue = new Subject();
private updateQueueSubscription = null;

ngOnInit() {
    this.updateQueueSubscription = this.updateQueue
        .pipe(
            debounceTime(500),
            distinctUntilChanged(isEqual), // from lodash
            mergeMap(params => this.server.updateEngines(params))
        )
        .subscribe(
            (result) => {
                console.log('HttpClient [POST] /api/navigation/post', result);
                this.procesEngines(result);
            },
            error => {
                console.log(`There was an issue. ${error._body}.`);
            },
        )
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.updateQueueSubscription.unsubscribe();
}

public updateNavControl(): void {
    let params: INavigationRequest = {
        engine1: {
            id: this.navControl.engine1.id,
            isForwardPropultion: this.navControl.engine1.isForwardPropultion,
            requestedPower: this.controls.throttle1,
            requestedAngle: this.controls.helm,
            correctionPower: this.navControl.engine1.power.correction,
            correctionAngle: this.navControl.engine1.angle.correction
        },
        engine2: {
            id: this.navControl.engine2.id,
            isForwardPropultion: this.navControl.engine2.isForwardPropultion,
            requestedPower: this.controls.throttle2,
            requestedAngle: this.controls.helm,
            correctionPower: this.navControl.engine2.power.correction,
            correctionAngle: this.navControl.engine2.angle.correction
        }
    };
    console.log(params);
    this.updateQueue.next(params);
}
```

The `updateQueue` will be a Subject where you dispatch all the changes and you can debounce them and use `distinctUntilChanged`.

Also note: `distinctUntilChanged` in your code will not work because it doesn't do deep comparison - for that you will need for example [isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#isEqual) function from Lodash.

Comment: This worked for me :)
I had to remove the typing of the params in updateEngines, but thenit works like a charm